# What is a "free type variable" in the context of Guava's TypeToken documentation?

Tags: java, guava

I am trying to create a `Map` with keys that are types. To support generic types, I need something like Guava's [TypeToken](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v16.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html).

However, I and am confused by some of the terminology in the constructors' documentation. For example, the second constructor:

> Constructs a new type token of T while resolving free type variables in the context of declaringClass.

What is a "free type variable"? What is the "declaringClass?"

Answer (score 2):

[In the class-level javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html), they give a usage example for that constructor

```
//                 free type variable
//                         v
abstract class IKnowMyType<T> {
    TypeToken<T> type = new TypeToken<T>(getClass()) {};
}
new IKnowMyType<String>() {}.type => String
```

You wouldn't typically be able to get the `String`. But, here, `getClass` returns a anonymous subclass which has `IKnowMyType<String>` as its superclass. You can therefore extract the `String` with the typical type token hack:

```
Type superclass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
Type actualTypeArgument = ((ParameterizedType) superclass).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```